# Count number of post in Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, count

wp_count_terms() counts the number of terms in a taxonomy but not the number of post that have those terms and I've found that wp_count_post() does not accept a taxonomy.

So whats a guy gotta do to count the number of post in a taxonomy term?

Example:

Term: Apples
Post: 89 (this is what I want to get, the number of post with the 'Apples' taxonomy)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are looking for is get_term()  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

and the code would look something like this:

```
$term = get_term( 1, 'category' );//for example uncategorized category
echo 'count: '. $term->count;
```

Comment: Does this count deleted posts as well ?

Comment: will count only published posts, which might or might not be enough

Comment: @jon-furry -- ``$term->count`` can be calculated to include other posts that appear in the ``All`` view of the admin table if you use the hook found in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316777/how-to-update-incorrect-post-count-in-taxonomy/404236#404236).